# Does anyone know why I am getting this eror message when trying to send emails through Jupyter lab

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SMTPDataError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-e02adfec2bdc> in <module>
     55         msg.attach(p)
     56 
---> 57         s.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, msg.as_string())
     58 
     59         #print('row0 = %r' % (row[0],))

~\Anaconda3\lib\smtplib.py in sendmail(self, from_addr, to_addrs, msg, mail_options, rcpt_options)
    886             else:
    887                 self._rset()
--> 888             raise SMTPDataError(code, resp)
    889         #if we got here then somebody got our mail
    890         return senderrs

SMTPDataError: (554, b'Transaction failed\nReject due to policy restrictions.\nFor explanation visit https://www.ionos.com/help/index.php?id=2425&ip=217.35.244.18&c=hd')
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to add an [mre] of the code that is causing the problem. I notice that the error gives you a URL which says it explains the error. Have you viewed this and made any progress to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This error is served by the email provider ionos.com (and the text tells you to visit their site at https://www.ionos.com/help/index.php?id=2425&ip=217.35.244.18&c=hd)

Someone else also had this problem (with ionos.de) and asked them about it

Basically they reject mails that doesn't follow RFC5321 and RFC5322 standards.

See discussion at: https://github.com/homematic-community/hm_email/issues/13

where you'll find the reply from them in German language which you
could rund through google translate.

Later in the thread somone has identified his problem: He was trying to mail several addresses and separated these with a semicolon, correct is a comma.

Maybe that's yours, if not, you need to provide a reproducable example.